# CRM Dynamics 2011 - How to create report (contracts, cases, actions)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I want to create report that will display information about Contracts and Cases. 
Contract for client and the Cases that are assigned to this Contract and how many resources are free after each case.

I've got one more questions. Are the default reports created in SQL Reports Services?

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your specific requirements, you may be able to build the report you are looking for using the built in Reporting Wizard. You can find this by creating a new report from the Workplace -> Reports area. You would likely need to have Contracts as the primary record type in the report and Cases as the related record type.

The wizard as you would expect does have its limitations, so if you are looking for something more, you can create reports using SSRS/BIDS and upload them to CRM. These reports can be build with [FetchXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928434.aspx) or T-SQL (On-Premise deployment only).

A few links on reporting:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328097.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2010/11/29/custom-report-capabilities-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx